# R: Iterative deletion of rows with group criteria

Tags: r, filter, iteration

I'm trying to delete rows iteratively, if they meet two criteria:

- slope column < 0
- max of Lfd within Ring group

```
Ring <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2)     
Lfd <- c(1:4, 1:4)     
slope <- c(2, 2, -1, -2, 2, -1, 2, -2)     
test <- data.frame(Ring, Lfd, slope)

  Ring Lfd slope  
1    1   1     2  
2    1   2     2  
3    1   3    -1  
4    1   4    -2  
5    2   1     2  
6    2   2    -1  
7    2   3     2  
8    2   4    -2
```

After first iteration they should look like

```
  Ring Lfd slope  
1    1   1     2  
2    1   2     2  
3    1   3    -1  
5    2   1     2  
6    2   2    -1  
7    2   3     2
```

And after second like

```
  Ring Lfd slope  
1    1   1     2  
2    1   2     2  
5    2   1     2  
6    2   2    -1  
7    2   3     2
```

I already tried without iteration:

```
test_out <- test %>%
  group_by(Ring) %>%
  filter(Lfd != which.max(Lfd) & (slope > 0)) %>%
  ungroup
```

And with iteration:

```
del.high.neg <- function(x) {
  success <- FALSE
  while (!success) {
    test_out <- test %>%
      group_by(Ring) %>%
      filter(Lfd == which.max(Lfd)) %>%
      select(Ring, Lfd, slope) %>%
      ungroup
    Index <- test_out[test_out$slope < 0, ]
    test_out <- test_out[!(test_out$Ring %in% Index),]
    success <- Index == NULL
  }
  return(x)
}
```

Comment: your first `ungroup()` lacks parenthesis. your function takes an argument x you never use. The argument should be test. Moreover, your function will create an infinite loop since you are not actually modifying test

Answer (score 0):

I think you are saying that you want to delete all the rows that have a negative `slope` and have `Lfd` that is greater than or equal to the row with the maximum value of `Lfd` and a non-negative `slope`.  If you want to do that within `Ring`, you can use the following:

```
library(plyr)
testmax <- ddply(test,.(Ring),summarize,maxLfd = max(Lfd[slope>=0]))

test1 <- merge(test,testmax)
test_out <- test1[!(test1$Lfd>=test1$maxLfd & test1$slope<0),-4]

test_out
#   Ring Lfd slope
# 1    1   1     2
# 2    1   2     2
# 5    2   1     2
# 6    2   2    -1
# 7    2   3     2
```

Comment: `max(test$Lfd[test$slope>=0])`     calls the overall max of Lfd from the whole dataframe, but not within the Ring group

Comment: That's right.  The question didn't mention anything about ring group.  I can  update later if you want it within ring group.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want - it will delete every negative row from the end of the data, until it hits your first positive value:

```
library(dplyr)
test %>% group_by(Ring) %>%
         mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
         filter(row <= max(which(slope > 0)))

Source: local data frame [5 x 4]
Groups: Ring [2]

   Ring   Lfd slope   row
  (dbl) (int) (dbl) (int)
1     1     1     2     1
2     1     2     2     2
3     2     1     2     1
4     2     2    -1     2
5     2     3     2     3
```

you can add on a `select(-row)` if you'd like the row column gone too.